# Tesseract OCR not recognizing text differing contrasts on same image

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am running into some issues with Tesseract 3.04

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDU0b.png) is an example of a case we are having trouble with. This example is an imitation of an edge case we run into after pre-processing the image with a threshold.

Running tesseract on the example image works just fine, but we are running into issues when the case above is part of a much larger image that predominantly has white text on black, with one small area containing black text on white. Using the example, tesseract only sees 1234567.

I have experimented will all page segmentation modes and all OCR Engine modes. Does anyone have any ideas to make this work?